# Why is there a DNS lookup from Bootstrap CDN that is no longer installed on my site?

Tags: wordpress, cdn, plugin, bootstrap

I am having a BIG problem. Most of the DNS lookups are suppose to be on the following site:
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/ytadvisers.com/6eIsggZE

Again this one DNS lookup URL will not go away.
netdna.bootstrapcdn.com

I was using the Bootstrap CDN plugin for WordPress. I have uninstalled it and this annoying thing is still there. Did I forget database files? Is there something I have to edit? It is messing up my Adsense plugin as well.

Anything to try is greatly appreciated, I need it gone.

Answer (score 2):

In this situations, this is what I will do,

login to the server using ssh, and goto wordpress installation directory, and use the following command to find out in which file the cnd link is used,

```
 grep 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com' -lr wp-content
```

So from the file list you will know from which plugin or theme the link is added.

If above command doesn't return any file, then it must be coming either from cache or from database. But it is very unlikely to come from database when the plugin is un-installed.

**Edit:**
In case you cannot login using ssh, add a simple php file in wordpress directory and add the following code in it,

```
<?php
     echo exec("grep 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com' -lr wp-content");
?>
```

Comment: I am on HostGator shared Servor with cpannel how would i do that?

Comment: if you don't have ssh access, you can also run this command in php file with `exec` or `shell_exec` function, if it is not disabled on your server.

Comment: this is what i got.    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grep 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com' -lr wp-content' at line 1

Comment: Can you please give me a command i can run in php my admin

Comment: ohh!! not in phpmyadmin. check my updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the speed booster pack plugin. The remove extra Font Awesome was on, turned off and everything was fine.